# setOnClickListener en fragment - kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

novato en kotlin, tratando de hacer una app, seleccione navigation drawer, donde desde un mismo fragment quiero 2 cosas, que mediante un boton en dicho fragment envie un toast y habra una nueva activity.

```
 NOMBREBOTON.setOnClickListener { view: View->
        val intent = Intent(this,NOMBREACTIVIDAD::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

esto no me resulto, estuve indagando pero no logro entender acerca de las lambdas y respecto del toast tampoco tuve suerte, tambien me parece que estoy errando en el contexto, estoy perdido. por favor ayuda. desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero lo que tienes que hacer es organizar el Fragmento, algo muy simple

Al momento de crear un fragmento al función OnCreateView se vera así:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_delivery_user, container, false)
}
```

Entonces para que puedas interactuar la Vista antes de que se muestre en pantalla debemos dejarla así:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.LAYOUT, container, false)

    return view
}
```

De esta forma podemos darle por ejemplo un setOnClickListener a un Boton dentro de la Vista o enviar un Toast con el contexto de la Actividad donde se inflo la Vista

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.LAYOUT, container, false)

    view.buttonExample.setOnClickListener{
        view.context.startActivity(Intent(view.context, Actividad2::class))
    }

    view.context.Toast.makeText(...).show()

    return view
}
```

En conclusion lo que estamos haciendo es darle las instrucciones de como debe funcionar la Vista antes de inflarse en pantalla

Comment: excelente, tuve algunos inconvenientes propios pero la solución planteada de matias es correctisima! gracias mati

Comment: es un placer ayudar